Best way to stream using langchain `llm.with_structured_output`
import asyncio
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class Joke(BaseModel):
    setup: str = Field(description="The setup of the joke")
    punchline: str = Field(description="The punchline to the joke")

# Define the model with structured output
model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0125", temperature=0, streaming=True)
structured_llm = model.with_structured_output(Joke)

def stream_joke():
    # Invoke the model and stream the response
    response = structured_llm.stream("Tell me a joke about cats")

    # Initialize an empty Joke object
    joke = Joke(setup="", punchline="")

    # Stream the response
    for part in response:
        if 'setup' in part:
            joke.setup += part['setup']
            print(f"Setup: {joke.setup}")
        if 'punchline' in part:
            joke.punchline += part['punchline']
            print(f"Punchline: {joke.punchline}")

# Run the streaming joke function
stream_joke()

What is the best practice to stream using langchain llm.with_structured_output? This just doesn't work.

did you find any examples in the langchain repositories, for example in the integration tests or in the ipynb files? If so, will you please link them here?

Streaming can only be implemented with the (unreliable) TypedDict. Then you have to parse the model output yourself. You may can have a look at:
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/how_to/structured_output/#streaming
